# SQL Query Inventory Aging- Eliminate rows of data until SUM=Another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking to create an inventory aging report. I will be pulling the data from my inventory transactions table against the quantity received for each part. I need my SQL query to only return the rows of data that we have stock on, for example if I received 10 of part #12347 on January 1st and 5 on March 1st, if I only have 5 left in inventory then I need to only return the row of data for March 1st.

Here is the code I am using to pull my data:

```
SELECT intran.fdate AS 'RCV Date', intran.fpartno AS 'Part #', intran.fqty AS 'RCV QTY',
       inmast.fonhand as 'On Hand'
FROM intran
INNER JOIN inmast
    ON  intran.fpartno = inmast.fpartno
    AND intran.fcpartrev = inmast.frev
WHERE (intran.fpartno = '12347')
  AND (intran.ftype = 'R')
ORDER BY 'RCV Date' DESC
```

Results

```
RCV Date               Part # RCV QTY   On Hand
2017-04-03 00:00:00.000 12347 1.00000   2.00000 
2017-01-28 00:00:00.000 12347 1.00000   2.00000 
2016-11-28 00:00:00.000 12347 2.00000   2.00000 
2016-10-28 00:00:00.000 12347 2.00000   2.00000 
2016-08-15 00:00:00.000 12347 1.00000   2.00000
```

Desired Results:

```
RCV Date               Part # RCV QTY   On Hand
2017-04-03 00:00:00.000 12347 1.00000   2.00000 
2017-01-28 00:00:00.000 12347 1.00000   2.00000
```

Because I have an on hand QTY of 2, I only want to see the most current rows where the SUM of the RCV QTY =2.

Once I have this data pulled I will export it into an Excel pivot table to show the age of each part.

Thanks in advance to everyone for your help.

Comment: `AS 'RCV Date'` is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: 'RCV Date' is just an Alias I used to make it easier to understand. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Anybody? I would really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with keeping the OnHand value in a variable:

```
declare @OnHand int = (select inmast.fonhand
                       FROM intran
                       INNER JOIN inmast
                       ON  intran.fpartno = inmast.fpartno
                       AND intran.fcpartrev = inmast.frev)
```

Then, we need to find out how many rows we need to return in the output. To do it, using Row_number() function like below will be very useful. The @counter value is to decide the number of rows we will need to return.

```
declare @counter int = 1, @sumValue int = 0;

while @sumValue <= @checkValue
begin
   set @counter = @counter + 1;
   set @sumValue = @sumValue + (select intran.fqty from
                                (
                                  select * from (
                                                 select row_number() over (order by id fdate ASC) as rownumber, 
                                                 fdate, fqty from intran)
                                                ) x
                                  where rownumber = @counter
                                 ) t
                               )
end
```

Then, all we need to use @counter to print the resultset.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(255) = 'select top '+cast(@counter as varchar(5))+' * FROM intran
                              INNER JOIN inmast
                              ON  intran.fpartno = inmast.fpartno
                              AND intran.fcpartrev = inmast.frev)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@counter int', @counter = @counter;
```